# XMLHttpRequest onload() function isn't passing a XMLHttpRequest object

Tags: javascript, ajax, express, http, xmlhttprequest

I have a function sending a simple AJAX request to my server. The browser's javascript code looks like this:

```
function testRequest() {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = () => {

        console.log("RESPONSE RECIEVED");
        console.log(this); // 'this' should be a XMLHttpRequest object
        console.log(this.status);
        console.log(this.responseText);
    };

    xhr.open('POST', `http://server_ip/test`, true);
    xhr.send();
}
```

The server code looks like this (Express.js):

```
app.post("/test", (req, res) => { 

    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.status(200).send("testing");
});
```

When the function is called, the response I'm getting on the browser console is this:

```
RESPONSE RECIEVED
Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, parent: Window, …}

undefined
```

rather than the expected:

```
RESPONSE RECIEVED
XMLHttpRequest {…}
200
"testing"
```

In other words, the server response is being recieved by the browser, however the object being passed into the onload function (`this`) appears to be some 'Window' object rather than an `XMLHttpRequest` object. As a result, there is no status or responseText variable.

When inspecting the request in the browser, the body of the response is indeeed the expected 'testing'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are using an arrow function `() =>`, in such functions the `this` is lexically captured and does not change with the context. In your case the `this` is pointing to the `window` context as that is the enclosing lexical scope i.e. where it was declared.

You need to change it to a normal `function` to make `this` point to the `xhr` object:

```
xhr.onload = function(){
      console.log("RESPONSE RECIEVED");
      console.log(this); // 'this' should be a XMLHttpRequest object
      console.log(this.status);
      console.log(this.responseText);
};
```

From the MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this):

> An arrow function does not have its own this. The this value of the
>   enclosing lexical scope is used; arrow functions follow the normal
>   variable lookup rules. So while searching for this which is not
>   present in current scope, an arrow function ends up finding the this
>   from its enclosing scope.